Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation violates not-null constraint
I have this Entity in Spring Data JPA:
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Users{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cons_seq", sequenceName = "cons_seq", allocationSize = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cons_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String created_by;
}

When I try to insert new record:
INSERT INTO users (created_by) VALUES ('James')

I get:
ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint

I use PostgreSQL. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Are you trying to manually perform the insert or is Spring generating the inset?
